# Use of extension methods

Tags: c#, .net

I have been using C# extension methods for a while now and I find them to be really handy. However I am not really sure of what is the most ideal situation to use them, I feel at times I abuse them. When would you recommend the use of extension methods ?

Comment: I think of extension methods as a place when you are not adding to the behavior of the class, since by definition an extension method can only make use of public fields/properties/methods on the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

IMO when either it's really an **extension** (and not a core/critical operation), or when it's a shortcut.

**An example of an extension:**

Often in sandbox applications (but it could also be used in real ones, of course) is extending `IEnumerable` with a `Print` method.

The print method **shouldn't be there** (that is: it shouldn't be a part of the `IEnumerable` class), but it's helping and making the syntax easier and cleaner. Also, you probably wouldn't want to ship a library with it as a part of that class.

**An example of a shortcut:**

Another thing I find myself often creating is an helper extension for objects with containers. Instead of calling `Items.Add` and similar, I just make an `AddItem` extension-method.

---

Something to consider is that it's just syntactic sugar, that is, it's for the you - the developer. So for .NET types and such use it when you think it's a good idea and will make things cleaner.

When it comes to "Should this method be an extension or a member?" see the first sentence in this answer, and also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787324/when-do-you-use-extension-methods-ext-methods-vs-inheritance) & [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/26/c-extension-methods---to-extend-or-not-to-extend.aspx) for more information.